# OSX software update download stuck forever

Tags: macos, mojave, mac-appstore, software-update

Every time there is an update in OSX 10.14, I am facing this issue. Software update download starts and hangs in between. After that, it never recovers. See pics:

[image]

[image]

Tried command line options as well as mentioned in other threads here but no luck:

```
Anujs-MacBook-Pro:~ anujaggarwal$ sudo softwareupdate -i -a
Password:
Software Update Tool

Finding available software

Downloading macOS 10.14.6 Update
Error downloading macOS 10.14.6 Update: The request timed out.
Done.

Error downloading updates.
Anujs-MacBook-Pro:~ anujaggarwal$ sudo softwareupdate --install --all --verbose
Software Update Tool

Finding available software

Downloading macOS 10.14.6 Update


Anujs-MacBook-Pro:~ anujaggarwal$ softwareupdate --list
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
   * macOS 10.14.6 Update- 
    macOS 10.14.6 Update ( ), 2582488K [recommended] [restart]
Anujs-MacBook-Pro:~ anujaggarwal$
```

I am currently on Mojave 10.14.5 and trying to update to 10.14.6

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you check your Internet connection and make sure it's stable?

Comment: Try downloading the update from Apple's website in a browser. You can mount and run the installer manually after it's been downloaded.

Comment: I am having the same problem and have been having it for over two days. It isn't an internet problem (for a change!). I have tried manually downloading the file from Apple, even on a different computer (a PC), but no go. Last night, the Software Update panel kept failing at 607.2MB. Then I would restart it and it would pick up at about 210MB and then fail again at 607.2MB. It isn't downloading, either from Software Update or from the web site. Is Apple having server problems? I don't see any on their status page.

Comment: This is a perennial problem now. Direct update package download happens like a breeze but auto update is surely broken. Don't know why Apple is not fixing that

Comment: Good to know that I’m not alone, taught my laptop is broken as it keeps freezing or not moving. Let me know if Apple already fix the bug of their updated software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manual update just worked for me. Downloaded the update manually from:
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2010. Mounted **macOSUpdCombo10.14.6.dmg** and installed the update from the package.

Comment: Yes, I am doing the same for the past few months now but was hoping for some permanent solution for this problem.

Comment: After failed to download this update from 100+MB to 2.6G 2 times with same error, I gave up auto update and turned to manually download above dmg...